# Private Key issue in Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

We are trying to make conversation between two SQL instances in one SQL Engine through Service Broker by following tutorial from MSDN. 
In order to make it simple , we send the dialog with Encryption = OFF so we do not need to deal with Master key , Certificate... and it works in the local workstation.

```
DECLARE @InitDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
```

DECLARE @RequestMsg NVARCHAR(100);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
     FROM SERVICE [//InstDB/2InstSample/InitiatorService]
     TO SERVICE N'//TgtDB/2InstSample/TargetService'
     ON CONTRACT [//BothDB/2InstSample/SimpleContract]
     WITH
         ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SELECT @RequestMsg = N'Message for Target service.';

SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle
     MESSAGE TYPE [//BothDB/2InstSample/RequestMessage]
     (@RequestMsg);

SELECT @RequestMsg AS SentRequestMsg;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO

However , After moving to the server , With the same script,  the target DB keep showing "Can not found private key , message can not deliver" in the SQL trace after initDB send out the message.

My question is since we set the encryption = OFF , why the target DB shows missing certificate ?

We use SQL 2005 SP2 , Windows 2003

Appreciated for any input.

Comment: If you really want to know "Why?", then I'm pretty sure that Remus is one of the maybe 6 people on Earth who might actually know.  Hope he sees this...  FYI, Service Broker has at least a dozen of these undocumented (or very vaguely documented) mysteries and not being a widely popularized feature like SQLCLR, etc., there is not much inof from MS on how or why these things came to be.  They just are.

Comment: How did you set up your transport security when you created the broker endpoints on the two different SQL instances? Windows authentication or certificated-based? Provide a script if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about coming late to the party...
Didn't seen this post before. I don't know if is still of any relevance, but here's the probably cause:

The [REMOTE SERVICE BINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166042.aspx) presence will trump the ENCRYPTION = OFF. This is to allow separation of developer duties from administrator duties. If Encryption is required by the Application, then the developer specifies ENCRYPTION = ON and the administrator **must** provide a REMOTE SERVICE BINDING. If the Application does not require encryption, then the developer specifies ENCRYPTION = OFF and the administrator **may** provide a REMOTE SERVICE BINDING if the deployment site decides that the encryption is needed, even if the application does not require it.

A [full description of how dialog security and authentication works](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/04/conversations-authentication/) can be found on my site.